# why the payment passes even I put code expired_card, without giving exception?

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I tried to make the payment online for my site, I work with `stripe`, the payment is done with success, but I add `CardErrorException` to handle special error messages, when I put the code 4000 0000 0000 0069 to handle the `expired_card` exception it normal pass without handling the "You card has expired" exception.

**CheckoutController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $contents = Cart::content()->map(function ($item) {
            return $item->model->name.', '.$item->qty;
        })->values()->toJson();

        try {
           // Enter Your Stripe Secret
             \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_PcRh9XreG5jbXyhCchJf9NCK00dku1xYGi');
            
            $payment_intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
                'amount' => round(Cart::total() / 100),
                'currency' => 'MAD',
                'description' => 'Stripe Test Payment ddd',
                'receipt_email' => $request->email,
                'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
                'metadata' => [
                    'content'  => $contents,
                    'quantity' => Cart::instance('default')->count(),
                ]
            ]);
            $intent = $payment_intent->client_secret;

            Cart::instance('default')->destroy();

        return redirect()->route('confirmation.index')->with('success_message', 'Thank you! Your payment has been successfully accepted!');
        } catch (CardErrorException $e) {
            return back()->withErrors('Error! ' . $e->getMessage());

        }
    }
```

Comment: What library are you using ?

Comment: @VincentDecaux `composer require cartalyst/cart` package

Comment: @VincentDecaux thx for you answer. I find these examples in this link [link](https://stripe.com/docs/testing)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is successfully creating a Payment Intent, but you're not *confirming* it.  [Payment is not attempted until the Payment Intent gets confirmed.](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents#apis)

The special test card number you're using that returns an `expired_card` decline does not trigger until payment is attempted.  That's why this code is not working as expected.

You likely want to [add `'confirm' => 'true'` to your arguments](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-confirm) (assuming you want to confirm the Payment Intent server-side) or [use Stripe.js to confirm the Payment Intent client-side](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/confirm_card_payment) (recommended).